# Error #1064 adding MySql datetime default value with fractional seconds

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, default-value

I have table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INT(3)
  , datetime DATETIME(6)
);
```

I want to add default value to datetime column with fractional seconds:

```
ALTER TABLE 't1'
CHANGE 'datetime' 'datetime'
DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
```

I get error message #1064:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''t1' CHANGE 'dt' 'dt' DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON
>   UPDATE CURRENT_TI' at line 1

Answer (score 3):

You need to use. 
 
Without the qoutes around the table name and column name. 
I've used backticks around datetime because datetime is a keyword in MySQL.
And you have forgotten that DATETIME needs to have that fractional seconds defined like DATETIME(6)

```
ALTER TABLE t1
CHANGE `datetime` `datetime`
DATETIME(6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
```